# How to keep separate membership filter annotation in MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, simplemembership

My solution architecture is as follow:

MVC 4 - presentation layer

Manager class library

DAL library

common DTO project library.

Now, I have added simple membership related classes and implemented.

Here, Problem is - `InitializeSimpleMembership` filter is existed into MVC 4 project and it contains - DBCONTEXT object... which is wrong as DBCONTEXT object or any DAL reference should not be exist into MVC 4 and I want to keep these separate into DAL project only.

Below is the filter code:

```
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
     public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
     {
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<FinalEFFirstContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new FinalEFFirstContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                {
                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("FinalEFFirstContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                }


                if (!WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount("admin@mydom.com") && !WebSecurity.UserExists("admin@mydom.com"))
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("admin@mydom.com", "password");
                }


                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
                {
                    Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
                    Roles.AddUserToRole("admin@mydom.com", "Administrator");
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
```

Please guide me how I could separate this filter ?

Do I have to move this class into Manager class library and add these all MVC reference there ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can consider moving the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` into your DAL layer (where you context class reside).

IMO it is fine to have a reference to DAL into your web project as long as you are depending on abstraction to access persistent store. For example, I derive my data context from `IDataContext`. The current datacontext which implement `IDataContext` interface uses EF as ORM. But tomorrow if we choose to switch to another ORM say NHibernate, all we need to do is implement `IDataContext` and change the dependency to resolve to new DataContext.

So you are right web project should not know how and from where we are accessing the data. That can be achieved by not giving a reference to `EntityFramwork` in web project. DAL reference is fine as long as web project does not get affected if you choose to change your ORM or data access technologies.

I can show you my solution structure which shows not reference to EF and filter in DAL, if it helps you:

[image: SolutionStructure]

Comment: if I move InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute into DAL then, how I could add as annotation on AccountController in web project? because, web project contain reference of Bussiness class library and not the DAL reference.